# Generating SSH-KEYGEN automatically and copying it from gcp instance to another?

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, instance, pipeline, ssh-keygen

How to create automatically run a SSH-KEYGEN ? We need to generate key automatically and copy from one gcp instance to another.

For that we need to ssh  within that instance and make changes within sshd_config file and change the parameter "permitrootlogin=yes , and passwordauthentication=yes"

How can we do this changes so automatically while creating an GCP Instance?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what exactly you want achieve ? How do you expect it to work ?

Comment: I am using GCP Instance and Jenkins to automate the creation of GCP Instance, for that I am using Google deployment manager that wil create an instance , I have written jenkinsfile , so when the Jenkins pipeline is triggered it will generate a GDM instance and it pushes  docker image in the google container registry, but  I am stuck in ssh from my Jenkins slave machine to the newly created vm.

Comment: Does my below answer help you in any way or do you need additional info ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use [startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) to generate SSH keys.**

If you to simplify things you can create a script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /tmp/sshkey -q -N ""
```

Upload your script into a storage bucket (create new or use existing one) and change file permissions in a way, that It will be readable by everyone; click on "edit permissions" and "add a new item" and fill the rest as below;

[image: File permissions]

Then you can create a VM instance with your startup script:

```
gcloud compute instances create test-instance1 --scopes storage-ro --metadata startup-script-url=https://storage.cloud.google.com/cfb1/my.script
```

You can run commands copying your newly created ssh keys onto other GCP machines too in the same way.

**But - if all the VM instances are in the same VPC and region (both conditions have to apply) you can login from one to another without creating any additional SSH keys or doing anything. Compute Engine takes care of everything and you can just ssh to one and type: ssh my-vm2 and you're in.**

Unless you have something else in mind (like VM's in different VPC's)

Comment: I have four VMs in the same VPC and region, and still have to go through the rigmarole of copying ssh keys, ssh to another instance, adding the copied key to authorized_keys, etc. Only then I can ssh from vm1 to vm2. So what do you mean that it is possible to ssh from one machine to another without any extra key management?